# Intellj IDEA，how to show the synchronized owns?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

In eclipse, when debug a multi-thread program, it can show the `owns` of synchronized method or code, like the following picture:

[image]

so, what I want to know is how to show the same information in the IDEA?

Comment: Can you provide some more context by providing an example of the code you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the threads view, but you can take threads dump and check it there:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot，finally i find the information under your help